# Use fullpage.js inside container

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, fullpage.js

I'm trying to achieve the fullPage.js scrolling effect **inside** of a container element.
The best way to describe it is kind of embedding another page inside the viewport and apply fullPage.js to it only.

In the picture below you can see the viewport background color is actually grey-ish while the container object is white. So the actual viewport should be static, non-moving, while the container should be the real scrollable page.

I know this should be possible by vertically stacking up `div`'s the same size as the container, setting `overflow` to `hidden` and then emulating a scroll effect using JS manually. However as fullPage.js is pretty reliable and featured I'd like to know if there's a little hack for this so I can save myself from all this work.

Kind regards :)

[Image of what I'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50qDQ.png)

## EDIT

Solved using the `mousewheel` event, an overflow-hidden inner container and GSAP. Turned out to be pretty simple actually :) Could need some tweaking with the y-Delta value to have more page switch scrolling threshold

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bva8g3u9/

Comment: Please share the codes what you have tried yet.

Comment: What seems simple at first gets complicated when you realise the extend of the problem. Your solution, to start with, doesn't work on Macbook trackpad, Apple magic mouses or some laptops trackpads, known as kinetic scrolling devices. Big issue there.

And of course, it won't deal with tens of different scenarios. Not keyboard accessible, no callbacks, no lazy load, no URL hash, no overflow scrolling when required, no non fullscreen sections available, will have issues with fixed elements.... there's a long list of important issues :)

Comment: If this fits your needs, go for it, but it definitely doesn't replace the use of a library like fullPage.js :)

Comment: Well I'm still interested in getting a library such as fullPage.js to work in such a scenario which would obviously be better.